# Какой сетевой интерфейс используется для выхода в интернет?

Tags: linux, centos, администрирование

На сервере есть 3 интерфейса:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
```

Как узнать, какой из них за что отвечает и какой за выход в интернет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Узнать какой отвечает за интернет можно с помощью команды `route`. Строка с маской 0.0.0.0 и есть выход в интернет. В правом столбце будет указано через какой интерфейс это пойдет. С помощью фильтров это можно сделать так:

```
route | grep '^default' | grep -o '[^ ]*$'
```

Virbr0 (Virtual Bridge) - виртуальный мост, обычно используется для предоставления доступа виртуальным машинам

lo (loopback) - петля интерфейс для связи с текущим устройством

eth0 (Ethernet) - подключение по проводу, оно как правило и даёт доступ в интернет. Также интерфейс может называться eth1, enp3s0, enp5s0

wlan0 (Wireless LAN) - подключение по беспроводной сети.

Comment: программа *route* [устарела уж скоро лет на двадцать] и запросто может отсутствовать в конкретно взятой современной системе.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Вы знаете альтернативу? В современных устройствах по-прежнему используется маршрутизация. Вот, например, у меня. Убунта 16.04, довольно новая система и `route` в ней есть

Comment: прошу прощения, я ссылку забыл вставить. ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста, с [этим уже стареньким постом](https://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=129712).

Comment: Фонд Linux об этом писал уже давно, тепереь работа с сетью это часть ядра - пакет iproute2. https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/shemminger/iproute2.git/tree/

Answer (score 2):

так как различия между «глобальной», «локальной» и всеми прочими сетями, в общем случае, практически несущественны (по крайней мере «с точки зрения» сетевой подсистемы), наиболее правильным будет получение информации о маршруте к какому-нибудь ip-адресу, который (с вашей точки зрения) является «глобальным».

например, `1.1.1.1`:

```
$ ip r g 1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1 via 10.0.0.1 dev enp3s0 src 10.0.0.10 
    cache
```

здесь `ip r g` — сокращённая запись `ip route get`, а ответ программы `ip` показыает, что пакеты, адресованные этому ip-адресу, будут направлены через интерфейс `enp3s0` компьютеру с ip-адресом `10.0.0.1` («шлюз по умолчанию» для этого направления), и обратным адресом в них будет стоять `10.0.0.10`.